# Persisting global data that needs initialising in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I have a global user defined type "foo"in a dll that is responible for the creation and deletion of a reference counted HINSTANCE. Problem is it needs to be initialised with a string by a function called on the dll.

What is my best option for doing this? How can a function create a "foo" that will be global and persist with a valid HINSTANCE over multiple function calls. Thanks

Comment: keyword `new` ? Singleton pattern? I don't quite understand your questions, do you have aminimal example/pseudocode to illustarte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a singleton:

```
class CFoo
{
public:
  static CFoo* m_instance;
  static CFoo* GetInstance()
  {
      if(!m_instance)
      {
          m_instance = new CFoo();
      }
      return m_instance;
  }
private:
  CFoo();
};
```